# replacing tag with another tag targeting class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to change the `h3` tag to a `<button>` tag targeting via `.container` and `.button-1` class using JavaScript. Unfortunately, it only targets the first `h3`

```js
var allWindow = document.querySelector('.container .button-1 h3');

allWindow.outerHTML = '<button>submit</button>';
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="button-1">
<h3>submit</h3>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="button-1">
<h3>submit</h3>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="button-1">
<h3>submit</h3>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="button-1">
<h3>submit</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're using `querySelector` which is always referred to the first-found element. I'd suggest that you should change it to `querySelectorAll` (get all elements) and use a loop to update all your elements

```js
var allWindows = document.querySelectorAll('.container .button-1 h3');

for(let element of allWindows) {
   element.outerHTML = '<button>submit</button>';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-1">
    <h3>submit</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="button-1">
    <h3>submit</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="button-1">
    <h3>submit</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="button-1">
    <h3>submit</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, for some reason its still targets the first div

Comment: Did you run my code snippet above? I think it's solved your problem though... @Lanline

Comment: As for your question, you're trying to make all `h3` elements to `button` elements, right? @Lanline

Comment: Yeah it targets the first H3 element. The code is correct i think there maybe other elements ive placed in between

Comment: I'm confused a bit... `The code is correct` is your code or my code? could you elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve? With these clarifications, we can help you to find a suitable solution @Lanline

Comment: Im trying to make all h3 elements a button. the code you placed i can see works on the snippet window. I have tried this out but doesn't seem to work. I think it might be due to me placing other div tag container in between (above each class " container") @Nick Vu

Comment: Hmm in that case, could you provide the actual elements you have had so far? That would help to figure out where you're struggling with @Lanline

Comment: Nick thank you so much for all the help, repositioned it. Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const replaceAll = () => {
    const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.container > .button-1 > h3');

    [...elems].forEach((elem) => {
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.textContent = 'submit';

        elem.replaceWith(button);
    });
};

document.querySelector('#replace').addEventListener('click', replaceAll);
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="button-1">
        <h3>submit</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="button-1">
        <h3>submit</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="button-1">
        <h3>submit</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="button-1">
        <h3>submit</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="replace">Replace</button>
```